# 3D Model: Edge Colors Mixing

Tags: 3d, xna, monogame, xna-4.0

I'm using MonoGame to draw a 3D model of a cube. [This cube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxYhb.png), to be precise. The edges are supposed to be pure colors ((255, 0, 0), (0, 255, 0), etc.), but as you can see, the colors are mixing. How can I stop this?

Comment: Disable DXT/DDS/S3TC texture compression (either in your app, MonoGame or your GPU drivers)

Comment: Works great. Thanks! For anyone else with the same question, see here: [link](http://www.shawnhargreaves.com/blog/texture-compression.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

These artifacts look like texture compression is in place. Disable DXT/DDS/S3TC texture compression (either in your app, MonoGame or your GPU drivers).